# find out if dataframe column contain word python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe` like this

```
 name    cat1    cat2    cat3
'aa bb'    A      A-1   A-1-1
'cc dd'    B      B-1   B-1-1
'ee aa'    C      C-1   C-1-1
'gg bb'    D      D-1   D-1-1
```

I want to make `dataFrame` of that `dataframe` that includes `aa` like this

```
 name    cat1    cat2    cat3
'aa bb'    A      A-1   A-1-1
'ee aa'    C      C-1   C-1-1
```

Comment: `df[df["name"].str.contains("aa")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `str` methods of the pandas series to perform string operations, including checking whether the strings contain a certain substring:

```
df.loc[df.name.str.contains("aa")]
```